# Bold text not showing on iPhone but displays fine on Android

Tags: html, ios, css, css-selectors

So I'm trying to get all the items in my menu bar to be bolded. I have several links that all work fine, but one does not. In my CSS there is a :hover selector to change the color of the button's background when the mouse hovers over each item. There is one that is different because it is a dropdown menu that pops up when you hover over it. Obviously, it has a :hover selector to display the menu when it the mouse hovers over it, along with changing the background color. When I view the code in a browser on my computer, it comes out fine. Same with viewing on an Android device. However, for whatever reason the dropdown item isn't bolded when I pull it up on an iPhone. I've even tried multiple browsers on an iPhone to no avail.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#menu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color: #A4C3FF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; 
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
  background:#325CBE;
}

#menu a:link, #menu a:visited {
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#dropdown a {
  line-height: 40px;
}

#dropdown {
  position:relative;
}

#dropdown ul {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 0px;
  background:#A4C3FF;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#dropdown:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}
```

So because it works fine on everything except the iPhone, I'm gonna guess that it's a problem with the iPhone not supporting the :hover selector or something (because only the dropdown does not show up bolded). If anybody could explain to my why it doesn't work and how to fix it I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile devices don't have :hover states because there isn't a persistent pointer.  In other words, since there's no mouse cursor to activate a :hover state, mobile devices will typically activate :hover styles on 1 tap and the actual link on a 2nd tap.  Some Android devices will simply ignore the :hover state and follow the link.

If you clarify your question, we might be able to give a better answer.

**Edit**:  I put your code into a JSFiddle for you.
It seems to work fine on an iPhone - http://jsfiddle.net/6vn91t8d/

> ```
> <div id="menu">
> <ul>
> <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
>   <ul>
>     <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
>   </ul></li>
> <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
> ```

Comment: What I ended up doing was making two separate menus - one for mobile and one for desktop. The one for mobile does not have the dropdown feature and displays fine on iPhones. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the <.select> and <.option> tags for a dropdown. However, people had also reported the bug if the device is jailbroken. Have you tried <.b> tag instead of font-weight? If it's working on other devices then that means it's "Probably" the problem with the iPhone.(The fullstops should be ignored inside the tags)